# Wann Drache und wann Drachen?

Tags: word-choice, idiom, meaning

Wann nehme ich das Wort 'der Drache' und wann 'der Drachen'? Ist es egal oder gibt es einen feinen Unterschied?

Comment: Related: [Warum ist der »Drache« ähnlich aber nicht gleich dem »Drachen«](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/23102/1859)

Answer (score 18):

Laut Duden:

> [**Drachen, der**](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Drachen)
>
> 1. an einer Schnur oder einem dünnen Draht gehaltenes, mit Papier, Stoff o. Ä. bespanntes Gestell, das vom Wind nach oben getragen wird und sich in der Luft hält
>
> 2.(salopp abwertend) zänkische Frau
>
> 3.von drei Personen zu segelndes Boot mit Kiel für den Rennsegelsport (Kennzeichen: D)
>
> 4.großes, deltaförmiges Fluggerät, das aus einem mit Kunststoffgewebe bespannten Rohrgerüst besteht

Wobei

> [**Drache, der**](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Drache)
>
> geflügeltes, Feuer speiendes, echsenartiges Fabeltier [mit mehreren Köpfen]

Comment: Why have they added that 'n' for all non-saurien?

Comment: @R2D2 I'm no etymologist, so I can't be much help in this regard. Duden lists Drachen's origin as a variant of Drache. Perhaps this addition helps to differentiate the two sets of meanings? We'll have to see if any other members can provide us with a more convincing explanation. I would note that derivations of "Drache" all seem to use "Drachen", cf: Drachenblut, Drachenbaum. [Dict.cc](http://contribute.dict.cc/?action=show-history&id=898424) also notes "Drachen" used as the singular nominative for the winged creature is dialectal to Southern German.

Comment: @Milchgesicht in the derivations, the n is a "Fugenelement". (http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fugenelement)

Comment: The distinction between *Drachen* ‘1. kite > deltoid, 2. harridan/bitch, 3. Dragon (keelboat), 4. hang-glider’ and *Drache* ‘dragon/drake’ seems artificial and may fail empirically, but except for 2. it’s actually very regular, because animate (masculine) nouns tend to prefer weak *N* inflection (cf. *Hase*). That’s why inanimate *Friede, Funke, Gedanke, Glaube, Haufe, Same, Schade, Wille, (Name)* etc. have almost incorporated the *n* into their stems which used to be – as for *Drache* – the suffix for everything but NomSg. Accordingly, their GenSg changed from -es or -en to -ens, cf. *Boden*.

Answer (score 3):

*Der Drache* is nominative singular: the dragon; *der Drache**n*** can be genitive plural: (of) the dragons. Or, you are taking about a kite: in this case it's der Drachen, too.

Comment: but I saw 'Die Schwiegermutter - der Drachen'

Comment: Good point. Same as kite, i.e. der Drachen, according to Duden. http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Drachen

Comment: I thought 'Schwiegermutter' is meant as dragon here, too

Comment: R2D2, the secondary definition of Drachen in Duden explains this usage: "zänkische Frau" ie nagging/scolding woman.