# Warum ist der »Drache« ähnlich aber nicht gleich dem »Drachen«

Tags: difference, etymology

Dass *Drache* und *Drachen* unterschiedliche Bedeutungen haben, ist mir bekannt, und wurde auch bereits [erläutert](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/13433/wann-drache-und-wann-drachen?s=1|2.1355). Mir geht es mit dieser Frage um die Etymologie dieser beiden sprachlich verwandten aber unterschiedlichen Begriffe.

Beide lassen sich auf das lateinische *draco* zurückführen, das seinerseits aus dem griechischen *δράκων* (*drákōn*) ableitet. Das lateinische *draco* bezeichnet eine besondere Art Schlange (»Tempelschlange«), die weder im Wasser lebt (*anguis*) noch häufig im lateinischen Stammland vorkommt (*serpens*).

Die Begriffe, die sie beschreiben, sind allerdings stark verschieden und werden in den vielen anderen Sprachen durch verschiedene Wörter gebildet (*dragon/kite, dragon/cerf-volant, drago/aquilone, dragón/cometa, lohikäärme/leija* …), wobei die germanischen Sprachen hier Ausnahmen zu machen scheinen (*drake/drake* (SV), *drage/drage* (DK)).

Als Arbeitshypothese nehme ich gerne an, dass ursprünglich ein Wort beide Bedeutungen umfasste, und sich diese später auseinanderentwickelt haben – nicht untypisch für Homonyme mit unterschiedlichen Bedeutungen. Wer die Frage beantworten kann, ohne die Hypothese zu brauchen, auch gut. Wer sie belegen kann, umso besser.

---

Wie entstanden also die unterschiedlichen Formen *Drache* und *Drachen*, beziehungsweise kann man einen Zeitraum festmachen, ab dem sie sich auseinanderentwickelt haben?

Comment: Der Duden sagt zu "Drachen", es wäre eine Nebenform von "Drache". Zu der von Dir genannten Frage schreibt Crissov: "The distinction between Drachen [...] and Drache [...] seems artificial and may fail empirically, [...]" Das erscheint mir richtig. Dies mag mehr eine Frage über Wörterbuchautoren als über tatsächliche Sprachentwicklung (die von ihnen natürlich beeinflusst wird) sein.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz Interessant, das entspricht nicht meinem Gefühl. Im Gegensatz zum Beispiel zu *Schildern* versus *Schilden*, wo letztere im Singular ständig mit *das* artikuliert werden, hatte ich das Gefühl, dass zwischen *Drache* (dem Fabelwesen) und *Drachen* (den dünnstoffigen Fluggerät) schon unterschieden wird … *Mein Drachen fliegt höher als deiner!* vs *Mein Drache ist größer als deiner!*

Comment: Nun, meine Ignoranz sollte nicht Beleg für irgendetwas sein, aber ich hätte nicht gewusst, dass "Drache" und "Drachen" unterschiedlich benutzt werden. Und wer kann beispielsweise sagen, ob im "Drachenboot" ein "Drache" oder ein "Drachen" steckt? Aber ich hatte mir vor dem Lesen der anderen Frage auch nie Gedanken darüber gemacht, ob es eigentlich "Friede" oder "Frieden" heißt.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz Für Komposita gebe ich dir absolut recht, weil die mit *Drache* im Zweifel mit Fugen-*n* gebildet werden. *Drachenboot, Drachenviereck, Drachenhöhle, Drachenschatz* … Beim Viereck, der Höhle und dem Schatz kann man sich noch sicher sein, welcher gemeint ist, beim Boot wüsste ich es auch nicht. Aber mir gehts ja auch nur um die Grundformen. ^^

Comment: Bis gerade war mir nicht mal bewusst, dass es sich um zwei verschiedene Wörter handelt. Für mich war der "Drachen" immer ein "Drache". Ich hätte spontan gesagt: "Mein Drache fliegt höher als deiner". Warum hat mich nie jemand korrigiert? Vielleicht weil ich immer einen Drachen steigen lasse. Akkusativ sei dank.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sowohl das Fabeltier Drache, also auch das Fluspielzeug "Drachen" haben den gleichen etymologischen Ursprung aus dem lateinischen *draco* (griechisch *δράκων*).

Schon sehr früh wurde ein [Drache als Wappentier](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drache_%28Wappentier%29) eingesetzt und fand sich auch auf Standarten im Feldzug bei kriegerischen Auseinandersetzungen (siehe auch [Dracostandarte](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dracostandarte) und [Draconarius](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Draconarius)).

[image] <sup>[Wikimedia](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/57/Draconarius_-_Roman_Cavalry_Reenactment_-_Roman_Festival_at_Augusta_Raurica_-_August_2013.JPG)</sup>

Daraus hat sich vermutlich auch der Namen des Spielzeugdrachens hergeleitet (vgl. Boris Paraschkewow: [Wörter und Namen gleicher Herkunft und Struktur](https://books.google.de/books?id=X_dv14TWVxcC&lpg=PA74&ots=dSh9BjJDaS&dq=Spielzeug%20Drachen%20Herkunft&pg=PA74#v=onepage&q=Spielzeug%20Drachen%20Herkunft&f=false)), der von Kindern ähnlich einer Kriegsstandarte hinter sich hergezogen wurde. Es wurde in der Namensgebung also nicht ein Raubvogel, wie das im Englischen gebräuchliche *kite* benutzt, sondern vermutlich eine Anlehnung an die Kriegsstandarte gewählt. Warum die Bezeichnung eine **-n** Endung erhielt ist zwar nicht erklärt, kommt vermutlich aber von einer Schwäche der im Mittelalter noch nicht vorhandenen normierten Rechtschreibung.

Interessant in diesem Zusammenhang ist auch die Verwenung in der Mathematik zur Beschreibung einer geometrischen Figur mit dem Aussehen des Spielzeugdrachens. Diese heißt nämlich im Deutschen *Drachen*, während man im Englischen überwiegend *kite* benutzt.

Eine andere Nebenbedeutungen von Drache(n) (z.B. Hausdrache/Hausdrachen) im Sinne einer zänkischen Frau leitet sich vermutlich von der ursprünglichen griechischen Bedeutung "scharf blickend" her.

Comment: Das sind alles Vermutungen, die schon recht unwahrscheinlich klingen. Dann lieber keine Antwort schreiben.

Comment: Eher wahrscheinlich klingt mir dieses hier: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drachen#Ursprung_der_Drachen , welches logisch klingt, da diese Fabelwesen ja auch fliegen können. Und zum Thema Hausdrachen leuchtet doch eher die Gefährlichkeit ein als die griech. Wortähnlichkeit, oder?

Comment: @falkb: und wo widerspricht nun der von dir verlinkte Wikipedia Artikel der Aussage von Paraschkewow? Und wie würde man damit dann die Namensgleicheit **anders** erklären? Außerdem sind fliegende Drachen eine eher neue Erfindung (erst im Mittelalter), vgl. *Lindwurm*.

Comment: Na, nix mit Flagge - Nachbau eines Flugwesens stattdessen. Und vor'm Mittelalter hat man auch sowas nicht als Fluggerät gebaut und gleichzeitig Drachen genannt - von daher kein Widerspruch. Ich habe aber auch keine Beweise, gestehe ich. Aber es hat bei allen Vermutungen doch mehr Logik und somit mehr Wahrscheinlichkeit.

Comment: Hmm, aber vom Wesen her bleibt es sich gleich ob Flagge oder Standarte, oder? Warum sollte man das Teil nicht einfach aus Spieltrieb oder Zeitvertreib heraus gebaut haben? Fragen über Fragen... Aber ich hab mein -1 erstmal weggenommen wieder.

Comment: Ich denke schon auch, dass man das aus Neugier und Spieltrieb gebaut hat, aber man hat es bei uns eben "Drachen" und nicht "Falke" o.ä. genannt.

Comment: Also, ich meine, man hatte dabei vielleicht gar nicht an die Standarte gedacht, sondern nur dieses Wesen nachbauen wollen, dafür bräuchten wir mal Belege...

Comment: Oder, das vermute ich mal, die ersten "Drachen" des Mittelalters konnten noch gar nicht richtig fliegen... Außerdem war ja auch die Dracostandarte dem Fabeltier nachempfunden.

Comment: @falkb Lieber diese Sorte Vermutungen als dumm sterben imho.

Comment: @Jan: Das Problem ist nur, dass solche Vermutungen oft schnell zur Wahrheit erhoben werden, wenn sie sich nur ausreichend oft im Internet kopiert haben.

Comment: @falkb Die meisten Leute gehen ins Internet, suchen Wahrheiten und finden Verschwörungstheorien. Auch Zeitungen sind vor dem Wiederkäuen von Schmarrn nicht gefeit. Wer nicht gelernt hat, einzuordnen, zu bewerten und abzuwägen, wird von vermeindlichen Wahrheiten überrollt, aber ist das ein Grund, Hypothesen nicht auszusprechen? Wissenschaft lebt von These und Irrtum. Solange niemand aus einem linguistischen oder germanistischen Journal eine besser fundierte Position vorschlägt, darf diese Antwort ruhig der aktuelle Stand des Irrtums bleiben.

Answer (score 2):

Irreführend ähnliche Formen entstehen nicht immer durch Auseinanderentwicklung von ursprünglich gleichen Begriffen. Es gibt auch die umgekehrte Tendenz, daß ein Element unter dem Einfluß eines anderen, häufigeren seine Form so ändert, daß es dem bekannteren ähnelt, obwohl keine Bedeutungsverwandschaft besteht.

Das gilt sowohl für einzelne Morpheme als auch für Lexeme, ganze Wörter und Konstruktionen. Beispielsweise hat das Deutsche verschiedene Flektionsendungen, die in ganz verschiedenen Kontexten auftreten (z.B. ist -en zugleich Pluralendung und Infinitivmarkierung), obwohl das Phoneminventar mit Leichtigkeit eine eigene Form für jede Funktionen zulassen würde. Ganz offenbar erhöht das Auftreten einer Form in einer Rolle die wahrscheinlichkeit, daß sie auch noch weitere Rollen übernimmt.

Ähnlich bei Worten; viele Homophone, die nicht Kognate sind, haben etymologisch eine Entwicklung *zueinander hin* hinter sich und nicht umgekehrt. (Bei Worten kommt hinzu, daß unverwandte Worte oft von uninformierten Sprechern als verwandt angesehen werden, was den Prozess noch beschleunigt.) Das Beispiel "Drache" vs. "Drachen", die beide fliegende Entitäten bezeichnen, ist hier typisch: ob sie ähnlich klingen, weil sie als verwandt empfunden werden oder umgekehrt, ist womöglich gar nicht mehr eindeutig zu entscheiden.

Comment: Hast Du denn versucht, etwas über die Etymologie von „Drachen“ in Erfahrung zu bringen?

Comment: Vom Prinzip her sind mir die ganzen Mechanismen bekannt. Vielleicht ist meine Frage nicht eindeutig genug: Welcher oder welche Kombination der vielen genannten Effekte hat denn bei *Drachen* und *Drache* die heute existierenden Wörter erzeugt?