# Warum ist der Akkusativ rein maskulin?

Tags: grammatical-case, gender, accusative

Gibt es eine gute Erklärung dafür, dass der Akkusativ ausschließlich im Maskulinum vom Nominativ unterschieden wird?

In der Flexion der Adjektive, Artikel und Pronomen weisen Femininum, Neutrum und Plural keinerlei Unterschied zwischen Akkusativ und Nominativ auf. Im Maskulinum endet die Akkusativform stets auf *-n* (und ist damit noch konstanter als Dativ Plural), während in seiner Nominativform (ähnlich dem Neutrum) Null -∅, *-r* oder *-e* steht. 
Lediglich die Pronomen der 1. und 2. Person (*ich, du, wir, ihr*) markieren diesen Kasus ebenfalls (*mich, dich, uns, euch*).

[image: Attributflexion]

In der Flexion der Substantive gibt es nur eine einzige Nominalklasse, bei der sich die Wortform im Akkusativ vom Nominativ unterscheiden kann und dann allen anderen Formen entspricht (Dativ, Genitiv, alle Pluralkasus). Dies sind „schwache“ Substantive, deren Stamm konsonantisch endet, z.B. *der Bär und der Löw**e** → den Bär**en** und den Löw**en***. Interessanterweise neigen manche Sprecher dazu, diese Endungen wegzulassen, vor allem wenn im Nominativ kein Schwa-*e* steht: *den Bär*∅, und manche Wörter mit Schwa neigen dazu, auch im Nominativ ein *-n* anzunehmen und dann „stark“ zu flektieren, z.B. *der Drache, den/des Drache**n** → der/den Drachen, des Drachen**s***.

Comment: Nominative sind unmarkiert, Akkusative markiert. Das Maskulinum ist unmarkiert, das Femininum markiert (aus heutiger Sicht ist das diskriminierend, aber die Sprachformen stammen aus einer chauvinistischeren Epoche). Man könnte also vermuten, daß tendentiell eher nur eine Markierung ausgedrückt wird als zwei gleichzeitig.

Comment: [Drache und Drachen](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/23102/15318) bedeuten [nicht dasselbe](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/13433/15318).

Comment: @KilianFoth –1. Femininum und Neutrum sind nicht »markiert«. Oder worin besteht die Markierung in »die Gabel«? (Leider kann man Kommentare nicht downvoten.)

Comment: @Jan Sich ausdifferenzierende Bedeutungsnuancen sind nicht ungewöhnlich bei morphologischem Wandel. Ich hatte erst ein anderes Beispiel, wollte dann aber durchgehend Tiere in den Beispielen verwenden.

Answer (score 3):

Auf Belles Lettres gibt es [einen ausführlichen Artikel](http://www.belleslettres.eu/artikel/genus-gendersprech.php), der eigentlich Gendersprech behandelt, aber auch die Geschichte der Genusverteilung anschneidet.

Der erste wichtige Anhaltspunkt: Die scheinbar unlogische Genusverteilung ist dem Urindogermanischen entsprungen. Deswegen »leiden« alle Sprachen, die daraus entstanden sind, unter einer unklaren Genusverteilung. (Die Sonne, der Mond, le soleil, la lune?) Und schon mit der Entstehung der grammatikalischen Geschlechter wurde sie angelegt.

Als erster »Baustein« kam ein Subjektmarkierungspartikel in Gebrauch: ein *-s,* das an das Subjekt eines Satzes angehängt wurde, und das sich noch im Nominativ griechischer und römischer maskuliner Substantive findet. (Im Germanischen ist es üblicherweise geschwunden.)

Als zweiter Baustein trat später ein Partikel *-m* hinzu, das wohl zunächst an Verbwurzeln angehängt wurde, und das Ergebnis einer Handlung bezeichnete. Auf Belles Lettres findet sich das Beispiel *jeug* (*anschirren*) und *jugóm* (*angeschirrt, das Geschirrte*). Da diese *-m*-Wörter grundsätzlich nur als Patiens (Objekt) auftraten, übertrug sich das *-m* auch auf *-s*-Wörter, wenn sie denn mal im Objekt auftauchten (*amicus → amicum*). Später wurden damit auch Gegenstände bezeichnet (hier: das *Joch*), und da diese plötzlich auch im Subjekt stehen konnten, markierte es die Geburt des ersten vom Standardgenus verschiedenen Genus: des Neutrums. Daraus lässt sich freundlicherweise ableiten, dass in allen indogermanischen Sprachen sächliche Wörter im Nominativ und im Akkusativ die gleiche Form haben.

Dass dieser Schritt evolutionär der erste gewesen sein muss, ergibt sich daraus, dass Sprachen wie das Hethitische, die sich sehr früh vom Indogermanischen abgespalten haben, nur Standardgenus und Neutrum kennen.

Das Femininum bildete sich später im Umweg über den Plural. Ursprünglich erforderte der Plural eines Wortes wohl noch eine Singularverbform. Man könnte sagen, dass Plurale als Kollektiv gedeutet wurden. Daraus entwickelten sich »normale« Pluralformen, die als viele Einzelteile gesehen wurden und die nach und nach forderten, dass das zugehörige Verb eine Pluralmarkierung erhielt, und »kollektive« Formen, die irgendwann als Singular gedeutet wurden (denn Pluralwörter erforderten ja nun ihre Pluralverbform). Der indogermanische Pluralmarkierer war oft *-a* und so sind im Lateinischen und Griechischen viele Wörter auf *-a* aus Pluralformen abgeleitete Abstrakta: *demokratia* (die Demokratie) oder *anima* (die Seele).

Jetzt fehlen uns noch Adjektive. Im frühen Indogermanischen wurde zwischen Substantiven und Adjektiven noch nicht unterschieden; man sprach von »einem Freund, einem guten«. In relativ unkomplexen Umgebungen führt das dann dazu, dass das sich entwickelnde Adjektiv zunächst die gleiche Endung wie das dazugehörige Substantiv erhält: ein*e* schön*e* Blum*e* (das *-e* ist durch Lautwandlung aus dem indogermanischen *-a* entstanden).

Und nun müssen wir alle Fragmente zusammenfügen:

- Sächliche Formen waren schon immer formgleich in Nominativ und Akkusativ.
- Weibliche Formen sind aus einem Pluralmarkierer entstanden; auch hier gibt es keinen grammatikalischen Grund für unterschiedliche Formen.
- Bei männlichen Formen ist die Akkusativform ursprünglich vom Neutrum geborgt worden. Sie gehört also eigentlich gar nicht dem maskulinen Nomen, sondern ist analog zum neutralen gebildet worden. Die maskuline Subjektform, der Nominativ, ist nämlich aus einer anderen Markierung (der Standardgenus-Subjektmarkierung) entstanden.

---

Obiges kann in dieser Strenge natürlich erst einmal nur für indogermanische Sprachen gelten. Es könnte sein, dass nichtindogermanische Sprachen durchaus in allen ihnen gegebenen grammatikalischen Geschlechtern zwischen Nominativ (oder vielleicht besser: Subjektfall) und Akkusativ (oder vielleicht besser: Objektfall) unterscheiden. Ich kann darüber keine Aussage treffen, denn die einzigen nichtindogermanischen Sprachen, die ich spreche oder radebreche, kennen keine Genera (und die Hälfte davon noch nicht einmal Kasus).

Answer (score 2):

Es gibt die Theorie, dass es ursprünglich nur ein "handelndes" und ein "nicht-handelndes" grammatisches Geschlecht gab (siehe z.B. den sehr kurzen Abschnitt in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animacy#Proto-Indo-European_language)). Nur das Erstere konnte Subjekt sein, hatte also einen Nominativ. Dieses Geschlecht wurde später zum Maskulinum. Für das Letztere wurde der spätere Nominativ aus dem Akkusativ übernommen. Später wurde es zum Neutrum. Das Feminimum waren ursprünglich Plural- oder Massenwörter (man vergleiche z.B. die Endungen im Deutschen oder Lateinischen).

Die Bezeichnungen Maskulinum, Feminum und Neutrum sind nach dieser Theorie also sehr irreführend gewählt.

Comment: Klingt nicht unlogisch, wirkt allerdings allein aus heutiger Sicht nicht besonders plausibel, denn die Nom/Akk-Formen des Neutrums ähneln bzw. gleichen den Nom-Formen des Maskulinums, nicht dessen Akk-Formen. Im Femininum gibt es ja, wenn überhaupt, nur eine Unterscheidung von direktem Kasus (Nom/Akk, „Rektus“) und Obliquus (Dat/Gen), während im Plural der Dativ (sofern möglich) immer sein _-n_ zeigt.

Comment: @Crissov: vergleiche lateinisch -um (Nom/Akk neutr. o-Dekl) mit -us/-um (Nom/Akk masc. o-Dekl), genauso -em (Akk kons., Dekl). Genauso -a (Nom/Akk Pl. o-Dekl) mit -a/-as (Nom./Akk. fem. Sg.). Die Antwort von Jan erläutert diese Theorie etwas ausführlicher. Die Theorie ist nicht von mir; für mich klingt sie plausibel (zumindest plausibler als männlich/weiblich/sächlich).